# Why don't the itemMargin of flex slider change dynamcially on window.resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I have successfully changed number of thumnails as per window size. I also want to change the itemMargin(Thumbnail margin-right) on window.resize but it doesn't work. Here is the working example:

```js
// flexslider starts
! function() {

  var Margin; // Right margin of thumbnail in bottom carousel 
  var Size; // Number of thumbnails


  function sizer() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      Margin = 10;
      Size = 3;
    } else {
      Margin = 20;
      Size = 4;
    }
  }
  sizer();

  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
  $('#flex-carousel-H').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 320,
    itemMargin: Margin,
    touch: true,
    maxItems: Size,
    minItems: Size
   
  });

  function flexSizer() {
    $(window).off("resize", flexSizer);



    setTimeout(function() {
      sizer();
      $('#flex-carousel-H').data('flexslider').vars.minItems = Size;
      $('#flex-carousel-H').data('flexslider').vars.maxItems = Size;
      $('#flex-carousel-H').data('flexslider').vars.itemMargin = Margin;
      $('#flex-carousel-H').data('flexslider').resize();
     
      //console.log("yes");

    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      sizer();
      $('#flex-carousel-H').data('flexslider').vars.minItems = Size;
      $('#flex-carousel-H').data('flexslider').vars.maxItems = Size;
      $('#flex-carousel-H').data('flexslider').vars.itemMargin = Margin;
      $('#flex-carousel-H').data('flexslider').resize();
    
      //console.log("yes");
      $(window).on("resize", flexSizer);
    }, 1800);


  }

  $(window).on("resize", flexSizer);
}();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/jquery.flexslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/flexslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div id="flex-carousel-H" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you can see changing browser window doesn't change the `itemMargin`, although successfully changes `maxItems` and `minItems`. Why?

Comment: I have also added this issue on github https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/issues/1642

Comment: you need to re run the function `sizer()` on resize. You are only running it one time. After it resizes, the function is already done running and has no effect

Comment: It sets the margin in the beginning but can't reset it

Comment: @NateBeers I have run `sizer` on `window.resize`. It is in the setTimeout.

Comment: @NateBeers I am not getting you `window.resize runs --> flexsizer --> setTimeout --> sizer` . So ultimately sizer runs. If you don't believe try adding console log in sizer and it will log after every resize.